# Single Post in Tab/Slider

Tags: posts, homepage, single, tabs

I have managed to code tab system that fetches different categories and custom taxanomies on a home page and shows relative posts. Now, is it possible that when someone clicks on one of the posts in some specific tab, then the post's content can be shown in the tab itself, instead of taking the user to the single post (single post page)?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) you can use AJAX to load the content. There is an example on the plugin page.

UI Tabs is always part of a WordPress installation and registered already as `jquery-ui-tabs`.

Comment: well, I didn't knew that. But actually what I meant to say is if some user clicks on Matt's Hotel then everything from the tab should wipe off and the content of Matt's Hotel should come up in the same that that is open.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. [See the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page), there is an API for link hijacking that you can use inside of a tab too.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. But if am thinking right then I have to re-design the tab system using the code for jQuery UI Tabs and then I can implement what I want to achieve, right?

Comment: Either that or you build your own AJAX handler for that. That isn’t a complex task: Just hijack all links inside of a tab, and replace the tab content with the link’s target.

Comment: ok, thanks. am on it. Will comment if I get it done or get stuck somewhere.